# mount command for mounting a fileserver

Tags: server, mount

I am mounting a network storage on to my local ubuntu machine. I have a question regarding mount command.

I am using this command to mount the network storage on my local ubuntu machine

```
sudo mount server-name /mnt -o username=XXX,uid=mylocalusername
```

There is also an option -t , which tells about the type of filesystem. Do I have to know the filesystem of the storage server before hand to fill in -t type option?

Using the above command, the storage server get's mounted and now I use

```
df -HT
```

In front of the storage server the type shown now is cifs.

Does this mean storage-server filesystem is cifs??

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not *have to know* the filesystem type.  From `man mount`:

```
   mount [-fnrsvw] [-t fstype] [-o options] device dir
```

where `[-t fstype]` is an optional parameter and:

```
-t, --types fstype
       The argument following the -t is used to indicate the filesystem
       type.  The filesystem types which are currently supported depend
       on  the  running  kernel.   See  /proc/filesystems and /lib/mod‐
       ules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs for a complete list of  the  filesys‐
       tems.   The  most common are ext2, ext3, ext4, xfs, btrfs, vfat,
       sysfs, proc, nfs and cifs.
```

So yes, the filesystem type is [cifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) and mount auto-detected that.